# SASS mixin - concatenate/collapse to a single property?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Im trying to write a simple mixin that will generate some cross-browser code for the passed property, but if you call it multiple times I want it to somehow append the new values to the existing property rule.

For example:

```
=foo($foo)
   foo: "#{$foo}"

.test
   +foo( test 1 )
   +foo( test 2 )
```

Will generate

```
.test {
   foo: "test 1";
   foo: "test 2";
}
```

But what Im trying to get it to generate is:

```
.test {
   foo: "test 1, test 2";
}
```

I know I could just do `+foo(test 1, test 2)`, but sometimes i might have many arguments and since the indentation based SASS syntax doesnt let you split mixin arguments over multiple lines (sadly), I want a cleaner way to use this mixin without having tons of arguments crammed in on 1 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sass does not handle what you are looking for – but you can workaround it using maps, global flags and include wrappers. Why I would consider the following an antipattern.

[Demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/LyEzVe/)

*Note! the following may need some elaboration but for now I'll just throw in some SCSS (for the broader audience) – I'm sure you can convert it to Sass*

**Global variables**

First we create a set of global variables to keep states and values across includes.

```
$render-map:();  //  map to hold key value pairs for later render
$render: false;  //  render flag if true we print out render-map
$concat: false;  //  concat flag to trigger value concatenation
```

**Render mixin**

To handle the tedious work of keeping track of what to render we create a multi usage render mixin. The mixin can be used inside other mixins to set keyvalues and inside selectors to render unique properties. We'll later create a small mixin to handle value concatenation as this is the less common use case.

```
@mixin render($args...){
    //  no arguments passed and not in the state of rendering
    //  1) switch to rendering state 
    //  2) include content (nested included)
    //  3) render render-map content
    //  4) before exit disable render state 
    //  5) empty render-map
    @if length($args) == 0 and not $render {
        $render: true !global; // 1
        @content;              // 2   
        @each $key, $value in $render-map { #{$key}:$value; } // 3
        $render: false  !global; // 4
        $render-map: () !global; // 5
    } 

    //  if arguments are passed we loop through keywords to build our render-map  
    //  the keyword key is the same as the passed variable name without the `$`
    //  e.g.   @include render($margin-left: 10px) becomes  margin-left: 10px
    //  1) get keywords
    //  2) loop through keywords
    //  3) look for existing render-map values or use empty list
    //  4) in case we have a concat flag concatinate render-map value
    //  5) in case we don't have a concat flag we overwrite render-map value
    //  6) add key value pair to render-map
    @else {
        $keywords: keywords($args);        // 1
        @each $key, $value in $keywords {  // 2
            $map-value: map-get($render-map, $key) or (); // 3
            @if $concat { $map-value: if($map-value, append($map-value, $value, comma), $value); } // 4
            @else { $map-value: if($value, $value, $map-value); } // 5
            $render-map: map-merge($render-map, ($key: $map-value)) !global; // 6
        }        
    }
}
```

**Render Concat**

To handle value concatenation we create a wrapper mixin for our render mixin handling the global concat flag.

*Note render-concat is only used for setting key/value pairs inside mixins – why it does not take a content block.*

```
@mixin render-concat($args...){ 
    $concat: true !global;     // set global concat flag for render mixin
    @include render($args...); // pass args on to the render mixin
    $concat: false !global;    // reset global concat flag
}
```

**Usage**

```
@mixin foo($value){
    //  add the passed value to the `foo` key ($ is stripped) of the render-map.    
    @include render-concat($foo: $value);
}


.test {
    //  in order to render our render-map content we wrap our includes
    //  inside a @include render (without any arguments).
    //  note the quoted strings to prevent sass from thinking we are passing lists
    @include render {
        @include foo('test 1');
        @include foo('test 2');
        @include foo('test 3');
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
.test {
  foo: "test 1", "test 2", "test 3";
}
```

As said be very careful using this... you could easily get unexpected output.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Man thats complicated for such simple functionality.

Comment: Is there any other way I can approach this problem that doesnt involve this level of complexity?

All I really want to do is set the `content` property multiple times and append instead of replace the value